# Possible security issues when running a web server on a home connection?

Tags: web-hosting, server, webserver, wampserver

I want to run a home web server, but I'm concerned this could expose my home network to security issues.

The server will run on a dedicated machine, with nothing on it except the os + lamp stack.

The machine will be connected to a home modem, via ethernet, and the network will be the same of my other devices: laptop, console, smartphones etc.

I will run some websites in the server, and I'm concerned about how it's presence on the web could expose my IP address, and consequently put my privacy in danger.

What are are the security problems I could encounter exposing my home ip on the net? If my server is compromised, will my entire network be in danger?

Comment: We have a lot of related questions here about that already. Listing all the cons would be considered an [open-ended list](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) question, and the last one is really too opinion-based since we don't know any of the details about your laptop, what you'd be serving, or anticipated audience... But in general, it's certainly feasible. Laptops tend to have slower drives, but if you replace it with an SSD and up its RAM, that would certainly help, and having a battery for continuous power is always a plus.

Comment: You'll want to look at how to optimize it for performance (e.g., rather than for graphics), using a server-based OS like CentOS would surely help reduce the amount of resources too. Have a look at some of our other related questions [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=home+server+is%3Aq).